# MacOS Mojave 10.14.6: can't install gevent 1.1.2

Tags: mojave, python

I'm trying to `install gevent==1.1.2` (I know it's an old version, but it's required from Odoo to run properly) on Mojave 10.14.6, but it keeps failing at the setup. I'm using Python3.6.5 and pip 19.3.1.

Here's the full error:

```
(venv) SlyK@MB.local:~/Coding/Odoo/11.0$ pip3 install gevent==1.1.2
Collecting gevent==1.1.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/8f/cb3224a0e6ab663547f45c10d0651cfd52633fde4283bf68d627084df8cc/gevent-1.1.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.9 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gevent==1.1.2) (0.4.10)
Installing collected packages: gevent
    Running setup.py install for gevent ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/SlyK/Coding/Odoo/11.0/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-record-8hpfz0el/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/SlyK/Coding/Odoo/11.0/venv/include/site/python3.6/gevent
         cwd: /private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/
    Complete output (109 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/backdoor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_semaphore.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/pywsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/event.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_util_py2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/signal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_ssl3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/builtins.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/local.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/threadpool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/subprocess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_socketcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/coros.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_corecffi_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/os.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_ssl2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/fileobject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_fileobjectcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/hub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_socket2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/win32util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/resolver_ares.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/baseserver.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/corecffi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_fileobjectposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_sslgte279.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_socket3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/select.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/resolver_thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/wsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    copying gevent/_tblib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/gevent
    running build_ext
    Running '(cd  "/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/libev"  && /bin/sh ./configure   && cp config.h "$OLDPWD" ) > configure-output.txt' in /private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/libev
    dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk
      Reason: image not found
    dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk
      Reason: image not found
    dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gawk
      Reason: image not found
    ./config.status: line 1166: 81287 Done(141)               eval sed \"\$ac_sed_extra\" "$ac_file_inputs"
         81288 Abort trap: 6           | $AWK -f "$ac_tmp/subs.awk" > $ac_tmp/out
    config.status: error: could not create Makefile
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py", line 516, in <module>
        run_setup(ext_modules, run_make=run_make)
      File "/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py", line 502, in run_setup
        **setup_kwds
      File "/Users/SlyK/Coding/Odoo/11.0/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/SlyK/Coding/Odoo/11.0/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py", line 305, in build_extension
        self.gevent_prepare(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py", line 302, in gevent_prepare
        configure(self, ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py", line 196, in configure_libev
        rc = _system(libev_configure_command)
      File "/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py", line 172, in _system
        return check_call(cmd, shell=True)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(cd  "/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/libev"  && /bin/sh ./configure   && cp config.h "$OLDPWD" ) > configure-output.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/SlyK/Coding/Odoo/11.0/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-install-0yoh2f4j/gevent/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/r1/qds_yjnx5xvb1w_fbbxcj_m00000gn/T/pip-record-8hpfz0el/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/SlyK/Coding/Odoo/11.0/venv/include/site/python3.6/gevent Check the logs for full command output.
```

What am I missing?

---

PS: I was able to make it work by creating two soft links as follows:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib
```

but I'm sure there must be a better way...

Comment: As you eventually figured out, your local `awk` installation is broken.  The underlying readline library was upgraded from .7 to .8, while awk was still linked to the old dylib.  The solution in the future is to reinstall awk from wherever you installed `awk` from.

Comment: Point is, I don't remember installing `awk`, probably because it was already preinstalled when I got this Mac from the company I work for. Therefore: how can I do that?

Comment: homebrew?  macports?  compile it from source?  your company's own package repo?  that is a question for you and your company's IT department.